# Scanner won't work on mac. I think it is unable to accept the int value from a method

Tags: java, windows, macos

I was being taught how to read files using scanner in my class. This code we wrote works on windows(eclipse) but not on mac(coderunner). Image conatains the text file used in this project.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

       String fileName = "/Users/User1/Desktop/example.rtf";

       File textFile = new File(fileName);

       Scanner in = new Scanner(textFile);

       int value = in.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Read value: " + value);

       in.nextLine();

       int count = 2;

       while(in.hasNextLine()){
           String line = in.nextLine();

           System.out.println(count + ": " + line);
           count++;
       }

       in.close();

    }
}
// Output Below
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: Image contains the text file used in this project.]

Comment: Instead of showing an image of a text file, copy-paste the actual contents as *text* into the question.

Comment: Just a note: *example.rtf* - RTF is not a regular text file. It contains specific formatting rules that you don't see in your editor, that would explain your exception. Create a txt file instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's ironic that if they posted text as text we'd never notice the problem :) EDIT: it's in the source file, I didn't notice.

Comment: thanks that fixed it for me. I found out on mac to convert rtf to txt there is a shortcut cmd + shift + t. I tired converting it by adding an extension txt before asking this question and that did not work I assume it was still in the old format that time. Again thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your problem, while the file is a text file, it's not a *plain* text file which your program assumes. It's using [Rich Text Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) which is a special format that can handle formatted text.

If you open it with a plain text editor (or using `less` in a terminal) you will see the actual contents.

To solve your problem you should save it *unformatted* as e.g. `example.txt`.